# How do I fully implement a custom type that safely behaves like a string in every situation

Tags: swift

Alright folks, I'm new to Swift and wanted to adopt some practices I did when I was in other languages. While writing this I realize though that few things just might not be possible because Swift for example doesn't have some implicit type casting.

So, I want "custom types". An EmailAddress for example where I can go sure that whenever this *exists*, it's safely an EmailAddress and not Romeo&Juliet by accident.

I also want this to behave like a String as closely as possible for developer convenience. What I've come up with is this piece (runs in a playground),

```swift
import Foundation

struct EmailAddress:
        ExpressibleByStringLiteral,
        LosslessStringConvertible,
        RangeReplaceableCollection,
        Equatable {

    enum ValidationError: Error {
        case invalidAddress
    }

    private let address: String

    /// Satisfies the "LosslessStringConvertible" protocol
    var description: String {
        return address
    }

    init?(_ anAddress: String) {
        guard
            NSPredicate(
                format:"SELF MATCHES %@",
                "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
            )
            .evaluate(with: anAddress)
        else {
            //I'd rather like to `throw ValidationError.invalidAddress`
            // but then it won't satisfy the protocols
            return nil
        }

        self.address = anAddress
    }

    init(stringLiteral aStringLiteral: StringLiteralType) {
        // I'd like to basically repeat the other init here to not have
        // the validation code twice, this one is just to satisfy
        // the ExpressibleByStringLiteral protocol
        self.address = aStringLiteral
    }

}

// nope it doesn't cast, but I realize now that this
// intended and a good thing.
print("Casts to address: " + EmailAddress("dummy@example.org"))

func demo(aString: String) {
    print("That worked. The string given is " + aString)
}

// compiler says: cannot convert value of type
// 'EmailAddress' to expected argument type 'String'
demo(aString: EmailAddress("dummy2@example.org"))

// this works though. While writing I guess that this is
// actually expected since their is no implicit type casting
// in Swift :D
demo(aString: String(EmailAddress("dummy2@example.org")))
```

I'd like to know your general take on this. Is this good practice? Am I doing "too much"? I doubt, for example, if rolling with `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` is still a good idea or it is too much overhead.

Also, as it's stated in the comments, I think I'd rather throw the initializer an Error then having a nil value (like it's the case for URL).

So, stackoverflow-wise, the question phrased would be: What would be a better take at what I'm trying to achieve since this obviously doesn't work out and I've deadlocked me a bit.
thanks y'all!

Comment: Which part of your code "obviously doesn't work" that you want fixed? The `init(stringLiteral:)` initialiser?

Comment: @Sweeper: I just end up fighting the compiler. The code as-is gives various errors and I now wonder if I even "want the right thing". So for example: when a method expects a `String` but I have my `EmailAddress`, would it be good enough to provide `String(EmailAddress("dummy@foo.org"))`? Or rather something like `EmailAddress("dummy@foo.org").toString()`? Or something neater I'm not aware of?

Comment: How are you "fighting the compiler"? Other than the `RangeReplaceableCollection` conformance, which I assume you omitted for brevity, your `EmailAddress` struct compiles.

Comment: you're right… I was running in circles. The only errors remaining are that there is no implicit conversion which is right I guess.
Then I guess the question remaining is about the overall code style, and how I could make the second initializer call/reuse the first, if that's possible.

Comment: I don't think you should have conformed to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` in the first place. If you really want to, how about `fatalError()` when the string literal doesn't represent an email address? As for implicit conversions, there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An EmailAddress for example where I can go sure that whenever this exists, it's safely an EmailAddress and not Romeo&Juliet by accident.

> I also want this to behave like a String as closely as possible for developer convenience

These two aims are in direct contradiction. In Swift, strings are mutable, so if you have an object that looks like a string, people are going to want to do things like append and delete characters. What if they (as one example of many) choose to append an `@` to your email address?

That said, there are strategies you can use to gain a lot of important benefits from the existing library. You could, for example make it conform to [`StringProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol) and then you'll be able to use it in many places where you can use a string. There are two problems with this:

1. It's a lot of work
2. You need to implement three initialisers which take arbitrary sequences of characters/bytes and they may not be passed in a valid email address. The only thing you can do is fatal error if that happens.

Probably the best compromise is to make your email address type conform to `Collection where Element == Character`. It's fairly straight forward to do this and you get a lot of the important functionality for free. In particular, anybody can construct a `String` from an arbitrary collection of `Character`.